# Unable to create working executable of electron-react app

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-react-boilerplate

I am trying to create a music player application using electron [Electron react boilerplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate).
In the development mode everything works fine, the routing was a bit messed up but by using useLocation to get initial filepath I was able to fix that. But after being turned into executable none of the ipcEvents are being fired or used anymore. I was using Tone js to play the songs by send the audioBufferArray using ipcEvents and then play it in react, none of that works in executable.

I used the build then package command that come with the boilerplate itself. I'm not putting any code here because I am not sure if it will help.
Please let me know if there's anyway to successfully create that executable.

Comment: Have you checked the **dev** console for error?

Comment: The dev console wouldn't open at all in the packaged version, and as per for the code, there's no error shown there.